# What kind of seatpost this is?

Tags: seatpost

Saw this seatpost in my spare box, any idea what kind of seatpost this is?[image: seatpost]

Comment: Are there any markings anywhere?

Comment: It says "kalloy - 27.2", no brand markings anywhere

Answer (score 3):

In one sense, the most useful information would be to know what diameter it is. You need calipers to be sure. Visually, it looks like a 27.2mm post, the most common diameter<sup>1</sup>. In some sense, you most likely don’t need to know what brand it is, although you could look for markings stamped on the post, often near the bottom. Actually, the diameter is often stamped there as well.

Not many bikes or bike parts are collectible, and the value of collectible bike bits is not really certain. I think most collectibles are likely to be a poor financial investment. I can say that it isn’t a vintage Campagnolo seatpost, which would definitely have some value for vintage bike aficionados. Or a vintage Shimano Dura Ace post.

Out of pure curiosity, this clamp design isn’t common. Tune is a German manufacturer of weight weenie parts, and they have used this clamp design. Some knockoff posts use it as well. Probably this isn’t a Tune seatpost, unless you can find a logo. In theory, that clamp design is probably compatible with carbon railed saddles, because it’s a top down clamp. Otherwise, any other modern saddle would certainly fit in there.

Footnote 1: on older bikes, other diameters that are close to 27.2 exist. Those include 26.8, 27.0, and 27.4. Thinking in Bayesian terms, the prior probability of the post being 27.2 may be lower if we knew how old the post was. Anyway, if it is 26.8 but you have a frame that needs a 27.2 post, you may be able to find a shim.

Answer (score 1):

In the generic sense it is a two bolt, zero setback seat-post. Visually it appears to be aluminum but could be some other alloy. As stated previously, the diameter can only be determined by looking for a stamping on the post or measuring it with calipers or a micrometer.

Answer (score 0):

[Kalloy is a company](https://www.kalloyuno.com/) that makes stems, handlebars, clamps, seatposts and other bicycle parts.

On their website is a long list of seatpost models both rigid and susupension. You may be able to match up what you have with what they are currently making. Here is the link for the [rigid seatpost models](https://www.kalloyuno.com/product/seatposts/r-igid).

If your seatpost is not currently being made you might find a match by [searching Google images](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=e1cf12f9f09085f6&q=kalloy%20seat%20post&tbm=isch&source=lnms&prmd=sivhnmbtz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi67KiQ-ZaEAxWMg2oFHQa8AkMQ0pQJegQIEBAB&biw=1361&bih=730&dpr=1).